# Can MongoDB be hosted in-process?

Tags: hosting, mongodb

Currently, everything that I've read indicates that you must run MongoDB as a separate process/service.  Is there any way to host MongoDB in-process?  If not now, are their known plans to implement such a feature?

Comment: I'd be interested to hear why you want to run MongoDB in process... What is your use case?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean "hosted in process"?

Comment: Not hosted in a separate process boundary - in other words, I want to host the MongoDB service inside the application that uses MongoDB as its data store.

Comment: The obvious use-case is a system where there is a single process accessing the data store, and one wishes to eliminate the network overhead, latency, and/or complexity from the architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my experience with MongoDB and my skimming of the [issue tracker tickets](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER), I don't know of any way to host MongoDB in process. I also found no evidence of future plans to do so.

I would recommend asking this question on the [mongodb-user mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user).

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is GNU AGPL licensed so if you include (link) in your application then the source of that application will also be GNU AGPL licensed. You can of course launch MongoDB from your application at startup and terminate MongoDB again when the application stops.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Embedded MongoDB](https://github.com/michaelmosmann/embedmongo.flapdoodle.de) library, although it was designed for unit testing purposes.

Comment: It does not run mongo embedded. It runs it as a separate process.

Answer (score 0):

Another Stack Overflow question has answers relevant to this question.

[Embedded MongoDB when running integration tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437226/embedded-mongodb-when-running-integration-tests)

Specifically, it mentions an in-memory MongoDB for the JVM named Fongo.

Looks like Fongo is mainly for integration tests and/or learning.
It may not handle all Mongo use-cases, but is worth a look.

https://github.com/fakemongo/fongo