# Does Mongo DB have an In-Memory mode?

Tags: mongodb, ravendb, in-memory-database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Embedded MongoDB when running integration tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437226/embedded-mongodb-when-running-integration-tests)

I want to use In-Memory mode for unit test, is there an in In-Memory mode like RavenDB?

Comment: Didn't you read the official docs?

Comment: There is no in-memory mode. See this question for some ideas about testing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437226/embedded-mongodb-when-running-integration-tests

Comment: Yes, there is now: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/inmemory/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is no in-memory mode for MongoDB. As per [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1153) link, this feature won't be included until at least MongoDB 2.8.

Though since it's using Memory-mapped IO, it should be as speedy as in-memory during the actual processing. Not the startup though.

Also, there's a hack to use RAM disk drive and put your mongo db there. That way it would be entirely in memory.

Comment: RAM drive is something I'd use for time being too, nowadays setting up one is really easy independent of your OS.

Comment: does it mean that RAM mode works for mongodb now?

Comment: check this link out: http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/49304254688/how-to-use-mongodb-as-a-pure-in-memory-db-redis

Comment: You can run MongoDB 3 with in memory storageEngine: mongod --dbpath path_to_folder --storageEngine=inMemoryExperiment

Comment: another side note related to this, is that folder still has to exist, because it tosses a couple files (eg. mongod.lock) in there.