# Can I configure MongoDB to be In-Memory?

Tags: mongodb, in-memory-database

I am interested in using a database that will allow high performance, with an expected requirement of cluster for a massive horizontal scaling.

We are looking into using MongoDB, does anyone know if I can use it InMemory (i.e. in the RAM - for performance reasons)?

Tnx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedded MongoDB when running integration tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437226/embedded-mongodb-when-running-integration-tests)

Comment: @teoman-soygul - not a duplicate. the Q you linked to asks about embedding the DB into an application in a way that it will auto start etc. this Q is talking about embedding it in the RAM instead of file based DB, wanted In-Mem DB performance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A performance boost approach you can take is to use a RAM disk

e.g.:

```
mongod --smallfiles --noprealloc --nojournal --dbpath <ramdisk mounted localtion>
```

---

See also:

- http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/49304254688/how-to-use-mongodb-as-a-pure-in-memory-db-redis-style
- Create RAM Disk linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66329/creating-a-ram-disk-on-linux/66331#66331
- http://www.phpmoadmin.com/mongodb-in-memory-database

Comment: Tnx, worth a shot, I have thought about it as an option while googling through threads ...

Comment: @SitnTheShade: What exactly is the point in adding a RAM disk when you can achieve pretty much the same with MongoDB alone? And on any supported platform pretty much the same way?

Comment: @Markus W Mahlberg - Do you mean the solution you posted below (updaing the syncPeriodSecs to 0)? if so I noticed that in the MongoDB website they specifically state that this parameters should not be touched ("Controls how much time can pass before MongoDB flushes data to the data files via an fsync operation. Do not set this value on production systems. In almost every situation, you should use the default setting."). Do you know differently?

Answer (score 8):

As of today, latest version of MongoDB, i.e. v3.4 supports in memory engine in their Enterprise software edition.
If you seek open source edition, Percona's MongoDB is way to go.

Mongo Enterprise edition : 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/inmemory/

Percona's MongoDB offering:
https://www.percona.com/software/mongo-database/percona-memory-engine-for-mongodb

Answer (score 6):

## Using a tmpfs

At least on linux, since MongoDB uses memory mapped (mmap) files, you can set up a `tmpfs` system that resides in memory.

Here's a neat [tutorial](http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/49304254688/how-to-use-mongodb-as-a-pure-in-memory-db-redis-style) on setting up a tmpfs for MongoDB.

## Memory mapped files

Memory mapped files are explained in more detail on their [FAQ](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/). It also says that MongoDB is automatically configured to use all available *free* memory on a system as its cache ([link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#does-mongodb-require-a-lot-of-ram)).

## Conclusion

Basically, there is no module for a purely in-memory database, but by using an in-memory fs, one can emulate it.

On a side note, I did find [MorboDB](https://metacpan.org/pod/MorboDB), a "In-memory database, mostly-compatible clone of MongoDB". Probably not useful to you, but I thought it interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is quite easy to do so. Simply set [syncPeriodSecs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.syncPeriodSecs) to 0 and disable journaling. In order to prevent most files to be created, simply start mongod with

```
mongod --noprealloc --nojournal
```

or the equivalent options configured in `mongod.conf`.

However, namespace files will be created whatever you do. In case you use a replica set, oplog files will be created, too.

In order to make sure that your mongodb will not eat up all available RAM and inserts don't throw an exception under those circumstances, you might want to have a look at [capped collections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/).

Comment: in the MongoDB website they specifically state that this parameters should not be touched. The site states that it "Controls how much time can pass before MongoDB flushes data to the data files via an fsync operation. Do not set this value on production systems. In almost every situation, you should use the default setting"

Comment: @SitnTheShade: I am pretty aware of the docs ;) Those parameters should not be touched for _standard_ use, as fiddling with them may greatly impact performance (because of unnecessary disk IO) and / or data durability. In this case neither disk IO or data durability are of any concern. But in general you are right – fiddling with those values is a Very Bad Idea™ unless you _really_ know what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Try https://github.com/nodkz/mongodb-memory-server

this helps for testing

`npm i mongodb-memory-server`

Comment: MongoMemoryServer v8.8.0 appears to not support transactions.