# How can I make an in-memory storage engine for a Mongo connection via Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I read in the docs that Mongo can be configured to be an in memory data store. But how can I do this with Mongoose and Node? The Mongoose docs did not specify this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26572248/5923666)

Comment: @RazLuvaton It is not a duplicate. I am looking to do this with Mongoose and Node. The answers to that SO question handles the configuration in the terminal via Mongo.

Comment: Take a look at this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-memory-server)

Answer (score 1):

The `mongodb-memory-server` npm package can handle setting up Mongo in memory via downloading the Mongo binaries to the node modules.

Straight from the [docs](https://github.com/nodkz/mongodb-memory-server#provide-connection-string-to-mongoose):

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { MongoMemoryServer } from 'mongodb-memory-server';

const mongoServer = new MongoMemoryServer();

mongoose.Promise = Promise;
mongoServer.getConnectionString().then((mongoUri) => {
  const mongooseOpts = {
    // options for mongoose 4.11.3 and above
    autoReconnect: true,
    reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
    reconnectInterval: 1000,
    useMongoClient: true, // remove this line if you use mongoose 5 and above
  };

  mongoose.connect(mongoUri, mongooseOpts);

  mongoose.connection.on('error', (e) => {
    if (e.message.code === 'ETIMEDOUT') {
      console.log(e);
      mongoose.connect(mongoUri, mongooseOpts);
    }
    console.log(e);
  });

  mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log(`MongoDB successfully connected to ${mongoUri}`);
  });
});
```