# Embedded MongoDB Attempting to download Zip

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, embedded-database

I want to use Embedded MongoDB with Spring Boot for testing.

Here's the dependency I'm importing:

```
testCompile('de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo')
```

Whenever I start the `SpringBootTest` the `EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration` initializes the `MongodExecutable` bean and that bean starts to download a zip file (version 3.2.2) from a url. How do I configure it so that it will use the zip file located within my `src/test/resources` directory?

Comment: Did you read the comments here: [Embedded MongoDB when running integration tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9830861/2313887) ? Essentially *".... It just gathers information about the current operating system and downloads the appropriate platform-specific MongoDB binaries from the internet ..."* which seems to be "by design". If you're looking for "mocking" then you probably want to look elsewhere, as this seems just to be an installer and instance runner.

Answer (score 7):

> How do I configure it so that it will use the zip file located within my src/test/resources directory?

I don't know that this can be done. My solution has been to have a copy installed (for myself and my team) in the following directory:

Linux : `$HOME/.embedmongo/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.2.2.tgz` 
Windows : `C:\Users\<username>\.embedmongo\win32\mongodb-win32-x86_64-3.x.x.zip`

This will avoid the need to download the embedded mongo for the Flapdoodle OSS, which Spring uses.

Caveat: If your team needs a different version of embedded mongo you can change the version for the EmbeddedMongoProperties class by adding this property to your application.properties (or .yml) file:

`spring.mongodb.embedded.version = 3.4.6`