# MongoDB how to test locally in Java a MongoDB database, like H2 with sql database?

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm developing a program that use MongoDB database but I'm asking if it is possible to use an internal database for test like H2 when doing SQL through Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/)

> Testcontainers is a Java library that supports JUnit tests, providing lightweight, throwaway instances of common databases.

Or look at  https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo

---

Update:

It seems that there is already an answer to your question:
[Embedded MongoDB when running integration tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437226/embedded-mongodb-when-running-integration-tests)